# Xcode 6 beta: Spritekit editor loses sprite

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode6

Been trying out the new spritekit editor in `Xcode 6` beta and getting this error - I know it's beta software but I just wanted to check with others to see if anyone else is having this problem or whether I'm just going crazy...

Spritekit editor keeps losing sprites - even the demo spaceship one

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Start new xcode project using spritekit game template
2. Goto sprite kit editor and drag out spaceship onto scene
3. Click Simulate, stop - then spaceship sprite disappears from the scene and is replaced with a cross (see video showing this bug)

http://d.pr/v/XX3t

Expected Results:

```
Spaceship should stay
```

Actual Results:

```
Spaceship and many settings disappeared
```

Version:
`Xcode version 6.0 (6A215l)`
`OS X 10.9.3 Build 13D65`

Anyone else getting this problem or have a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed this as a bug with Apple and they acknowledged this. It appears to have been fixed now as of XCode Version 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I've been having problems with the SpriteKit scene editor in Xcode v6.0.1. After I added a node to a scene I wasn't able to select it. I tried Xcode 6.1 GM and the scene editor works a lot better. The sprite selection bug is gone and the scene refreshes in realtime as you edit it. I think your bug will be fixed too in this version.